# Get pair of elements from array whose value is equal to specific sum using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array as [2, 7, 5, 3, 9] I was trying to find the pair of values from the array whose sum would be equal to 12 and below is the code that I wrote

```js
let arr1 = [2, 7, 5, 3, 9]
let addSum = 12;

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let diff = addSum - arr1[i];
  if (arr1.includes(diff)) {
    console.log('Arr pair has value' + diff + ': ' + arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

but the issue i'm facing is the value are duplicated in the console as given below -

```
Arr pair has value5: 7
Arr pair has value7: 5
Arr pair has value9: 3
Arr pair has value3: 9
```

if i already have `(5,7)` it should not be repeated as `(7,5)` how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only print the cases where `diff` is less than `arr[i]`.

```js
let arr1 = [2, 7, 5, 3, 9]
let addSum = 12;

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let diff = addSum - arr1[i];
  if (diff < arr1[i] && arr1.includes(diff)) {
    console.log('Arr pair has value ' + diff + ': ' + arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to remove the other item index from the array when found:

```js
let arr = [2, 7, 5, 3, 9]
let addSum = 12;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let diff = addSum - arr[i];
    const index = arr.indexOf(diff);
    if (index !== -1) {
        console.log('Arr pair has value' + arr[index] + ': '+arr[i]);
        arr.splice(index, 1);
        i--; // to avoid skipping the next one from the array indicies shifting down
    }
}
```

Another solution with better time complexity (`O(n)` instead of `O(n ^ 2)`) would be to put the items into a Set instead, assuming duplicates aren't an issue:

```js
const set = new Set([2, 7, 5, 3, 9]);
let addSum = 12;
for (const item of set) {
  const diff = addSum - item;
  if (set.has(diff)) {
    console.log('Arr pair has value' + item + ': '+diff);
    set.delete(diff);
  }
}
```

If duplicates *are* a possibility you need to account for, use a Map (or object) instead, where the values are the number of times the key (the number) has been found in the original array. When a key that matches a diff is found, log only if the value is greater than 0, and decrement that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to strip duplicates from your list of results, store each `diff` in an array and check if the `diff` or the `diff`'s difference already exist as a pair:

```js
let arr1 = [2, 7, 5, 3, 9]
let addSum = 12;
let diffs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let diff = addSum - arr1[i];
  if (arr1.includes(diff)) {
    diffs.push(diff);
    if (!diffs.includes(addSum - diff)) {
      console.log('Arr pair has value ' + diff + ':' + arr1[i]);
    } else {
      diffs.push(arr1[i]);
    }
  }
}
```